# Searching for element in a column by iterating over the column, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

In my data frame I need to remove columns that contain a specific character. In order to search for those columns, I am trying to write a for loop in python that iterate over each column and, if find a column with the unwanted character, this column has to be dropped out.
My data frame appears like this and I need to drop col3 and col5 that have 'f' and 't'

```
col1  col2  col3 col4 col5 col6
1245  pink  f    Mar  f    f
245   green f    Feb  t    f
1237  grey  t    Apr  f    f
267   black f    Sep  t    f
```

I am trying to write a script similar to this

```
for col in df.items():
       if df[col] == 'f'
       df = df.drop([col], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a boolean mask of the columns which contains only `f` and then apply the mask to the df:

```
mask = ((df == 'f') | (df=='t')).all(0)
df = df[df.columns[~mask]]
```

If you want to leave column 6, you could do so:

```
mask0 = ((df == 'f') | (df == 't')).all(0)
mask1 = (df == 'f').all(0)
df0 = df[df.columns[~mask0]] 
df1 = df[df.columns[mask1]]
df = pd.concat([df0, df1], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe. I got again the error as the other suggestion: 'Could not compare ['f'] with block values'

Comment: Can you post some of the real df?

Comment: @Annalix maybe you are trying to compare string with numerical values. You could try with: `df = df.astype(np.object)` so they are all the same type. Check the type of the columns with `df.info()`

Comment: Fixed the type problem. Thanks so much! Now, as explained I have just discovered that my columns contain also 't'. See update dataframe in the post.

Comment: @Annalix I've updated the answer, but does the column 6 have to stay? and if there is a different value, should the column stay or being deleted?

Comment: Great! No col6 doesn't need to stay and your solution works. Thanks a lot. I wanted to use & instead of |. At this point can I ask you how would be id I would need the col6 to stay? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Annalix You are welcome, glad to help :) I've updated the answer. Probably there is a shorter way to do it, but this is quite intuitive

Answer (score 1):

With `pd.DataFrame.loc` and `pd.DataFrame.any` functions:

```
In [196]: df
Out[196]: 
   col1   col2 col3 col4 col5
0  1245   pink    t  Mar    f
1   245  green    f  Feb    t
2  1237   grey    f  Apr    f
3   267  black    f  Sep    f
4   111    red    t  Aug    t

In [197]: df.loc[:, ~((df == 'f') | (df == 't')).any(axis=0)]
Out[197]: 
   col1   col2 col4
0  1245   pink  Mar
1   245  green  Feb
2  1237   grey  Apr
3   267  black  Sep
4   111    red  Aug
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got this error: 'Could not compare ['f'] with block values'

Comment: @Annalix, see my update where I've printed the initial `df` structure, check if you posted the actual dataframe

Comment: My actual dataframe is much more complex, with 200 columns, that's why I need to write a script. Anyway the dataframe posted is the same...what does mean block values?

Comment: @Annalix, I suppose you have some other values in columns `col3` and `col5` except `f` , right?

Comment: I have updated the dtype to all object type and now both scripts suggested by you and @Joe works. Doing this I have discovered that you are write, there is also a 't'. Sorry but I have hundred od columns and a lot of them are similar, containing 't' and 'f' that I need to IDENTIFY and then remove.

Comment: So, now I have dropped the columns containing only  'f'. Now I need to identify and drop also those containing both 't' and 'f'. Should I integrate with a (df == 'f' & df == 't')?